# regex match specific pattern

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have

```
[root@centos64 ~]# cat /tmp/out
[
  "i-b7a82af5",
  "i-9d78f4df",
  "i-92ea58d0",
  "i-fa4acab8"
]
```

I would like to pipe though sed or grep to match the format "x-xxxxxxxx" i.e. a mix of a-z 0-9 always in 1-[8 chars length], and omit everything else

```
[root@centos64 ~]# cat /tmp/out| sed s/x-xxxxxxxx/
i-b7a82af5
i-9d78f4df
i-92ea58d0
i-fa4acab8
```

I know this is basic, but I can only find examples of text substitution.

Comment: The `sed` documentation doesn't include anything about the `p` command to print the lines that match a regular expression?

Comment: Why do you have to use `sed`? Isn't this what `grep` is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*([a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]{8}).*/\1/p' file
i-b7a82af5
i-9d78f4df
i-92ea58d0
i-fa4acab8
```

Comment: @Jepper your locale setting will affect whether `a-z` means `lower case letters` or `all letters except Z` or something else. Use `[[:lower:][:digit:]]` instead of `[a-z0-9]` if you want lower case letters or digits. If you want any alpha-numeric then use `[[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
grep -Eo '[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]{8}' file
```

The `-E` option makes it recognize extended regular expressions, so it can use `{8}` to match 8 repetitions.

The `-o` option makes it only print the part of the line that matches the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just print whatever's between the quotes:

```
$ sed -n 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file
i-b7a82af5
i-9d78f4df
i-92ea58d0
i-fa4acab8

$ awk -F\" 'NF>1{print $2}' file                     
i-b7a82af5
i-9d78f4df
i-92ea58d0
i-fa4acab8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you need: `[0-9a-zA-Z]-[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}`. Try it out [here](http://regex101.com/r/iR6bH0/1).

Answer (score 0):

This should work `^[a-z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$`